# Misleading message on trying to edit a "known good" audit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, edits, review-audits

I wanted to edit an answer in the Low Quality review queue. It was a "known good" audit, so the message said:

> If you still want to edit it, use the link to the right to return to the post.

Yes, I wanted to edit that. But "the link to the right" is Next, which moves me forward to the next post. I eventually got back through *history*. If *history* is the link that the message meant, it should say so explicitly:

> If you still want to edit it, use the [history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) link to   return to the post.

Servy's answer suggests that the message refers to the link eloquently named "link" (which is cut off on my screenshot). That wasn't obvious from the message at all.

---

> [image: passed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clicked the wrong link.  The link to edit the post is not the "next" button, but rather the link that says, "link".

> [image]